# Fonts for two applets in processing

Tags: fonts, processing

How can I change the font on the second applet? I was trying change it in settings() or setup(), but it only affects fonts on the first screen, and sometimes I have an error NullPointException. Thanks.

```java
PFont font;

void setup() {
  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
  font = loadFont("Arial-Black-30.vlw");
  textFont(font);  
}
void settings() {  
  size(300, 100);
}
void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  text("Hello world!",50,40);
}   


public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 200);

  }
  public void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(0);  
    text("Hello world!",50,40);

  }
}
```

Comment: Processing sketches are one sketch per file. If you have two sketches, you need to literally make two sketches (different files, saved with different names). If you need an offscreen buffer, then you should be using `PGraphics` for that, not an instance of PApplet (which is technically *not* Processing anymore, now you're using code that is only going to work when your Processing sketch runs on a JVM rather than something that explicitly supports the Processing API)

Answer (score 0):

The code you posted never sets the font of the second sketch. It only sets the font of the first sketch.

If you want to use the `font` variable in your second sketch, you first have to make sure it's loaded before you run your second sketch. In other words, your first sketch's `setup()` needs to look like this, with `loadFont()` happening before `runSketch()`:

```java
void setup() {

  font = loadFont("Arial-Black-30.vlw");
  textFont(font);  

  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);
}
```

Then if you want to use `font` in your second sketch, you have to do it from `setup()` or `draw()`, not from `settings()`.

```
public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 200);
  }

  public void setup() {
    textFont(font);
  }

  public void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(0);  
    text("Hello world!", 50, 40);
  }
}
```

Putting it all together, it looks like this:

```
PFont font;

void setup() {

  font = createFont("SourceCodePro-Regular.ttf", 24);

  String[] args = {"TwoFrameTest"};
  SecondApplet sa = new SecondApplet();
  PApplet.runSketch(args, sa);

  textFont(font);
}

void settings() {  
  size(300, 100);
}

void draw() {
  background(0);
  fill(255);
  text("Hello world!", 50, 40);
}   


public class SecondApplet extends PApplet {

  public void settings() {
    size(200, 200);
  }

  public void setup() {
    textFont(font);
  }

  public void draw() {
    background(255);
    fill(0);  
    text("Hello world!", 50, 40);
  }
}
```